# How can I execute a PHP script without waiting for completion before the page loads for the end user?

Tags: php, ajax

I am working on a site plugin that takes advantage of the YouTube API to grab some data for a specific channel. The problem is that the code takes several seconds to load on larger channels meaning the user has to wait quite a bit of time for the script to finish loading before they can view each page. Most of the time the data retrieved isn't even relevant to them but the script still needs to run its checks. So how can I initialize the PHP script without the user having to wait for it?

My first thought is to use AJAX and make a request to the remote script but will that cause parts of the page to hang as the script is running? I don't need the results from the script, I just need the script to run and do its own thing.

Comment: U can use `ignore_user_abort(true);` 
Also be sure to close the session, if any, at the beginning of the page. Otherwise u'll leave a lock in place, which prevents the user of starting a new request.

Comment: @DarkBee Where would I close the session? This is part of a WordPress plugin, would closing the session disrupt other parts of WordPress? Or can I close the session just for the script I am calling?

Comment: In the script u are calling with ajax

Comment: @DarkBee Okay, so call the script with AJAX, ignore the user abort, and then close the session, which won't matter because it's called via AJAX. Got it!

Answer (score 0):

You can use exec to start a separate PHP script. And adding `&` at the end will make exec return imidiately.

Let script.php do the heavy stuff and call it from a mall script like so:

```
exec("php script.php > /dev/null &");
```

You need to have a *nix server environment. Don't think it will work on Windows platform.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX stands for **Asynchronous** JavaScript and XML, which means that, when using it, the execution of the rest of the code will not be blocked.

You can make an AJAX request to the script you want to execute and then keep rendering the page normally. The AJAX request will be performed in the background, and won't be of any disturb whatsoever.